# How do i increment and display likes on a page?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, view, model, controller

I'm new to **RoR** and I'm trying to have a *up/down like* counter for the products on each specific page. I'm struggling trying to figure out how to get the counter to **display on the page**.

Here's my **model**

```
class Rating < ActiveRecord::Base

    def total(total)
        @total = total
        @like = Rating.find(:like, params[:id])
        @dislike = Rating.find(:dislike, params[:id])
        @like + @dislike = total
    end
    def average(average)
        @average = average
        average.to_f = (total / 2)
    end
    def overall(overall)
        @overall = overall
        if @like > average
            overall = "More liked"
        elsif @dislike > average
            overall = "More disliked"
        else
            overall = nil
        end
    end
end
```

my **controller**

```
class RatingController < ApplicationController

    def new
        @rating = Rating.new
    end
    def index
        @rating = Rating.all
    end
    def can_rate(user_sign)
        @user_sign = user_sign
        user_signed_in? == true ? (user_sign == true) : (user_sign = false)
    end



    def like(liked)
        @liked = liked

        if can_rate?
            unless liked == true
                liked = true
                #Checks if dislike is true and subtracts it if it is
                if disliked == true
                    Rating.decrement_counter(:dislike, params[:id])
                    disliked = false
                end

                Rating.increment_counter(:like, params[:id])
                rating_id = Rating.find(params[:id])
                rating_id.save
                flash[:notice] = "You liked this!"  
            else 
                disliked = nil
                liked = nil
                Rating.decrement_counter(:like, params[:id])
                rating_id.save
            end
        else
            flash[:alert] = "You need to be signed in to use this feature!"
        end
        redirect_to :back
    end



    def dislike(disliked)
        @disliked = disliked

        if can_rate?
            unless disliked == true
                #Checks if dislike is true and subtracts it if it is
                if liked = true
                    Rating.decrement_counter(:like, params[:id])
                    liked = false
                end

                disliked = true
                Rating.increment_counter(:dislike, params[:id])
                rating_id = Rating.find(params[:id])
                rating_id.save
                flash[:notice] = "You disliked this!"
            else
                disliked = nil
                liked = nil
                Rating.decrement_counter(:like, params[:id])
                rating_id.save
            end
        else
            flash[:alert] = "You need to be signed in to use this feature!" 
        end
        redirect_to :back
    end
end
```

my **index** (just testing to see if it worked)

```
<h1 style='text-align: center; border-bottom: 2px solid #ddd;'>Hello world!</h1>
<div>
<%= link_to 'like',  :method => :like, :remote=>true %>
</div>
```

and finally my **routes**

```
match '/rating', :to => 'rating#index', :as => :rating, via: 'get'
resources :rating
```

Comment: have you checked out the [rails guide on templates](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_view_overview.html#templates-partials-and-layouts)?

Comment: Hi and welcome to Stack overflow. I'll point out a few small things and see where we can go from there to figure out what's wrong. Firstly: `@like + @dislike = total` I don't even know what you're trying to do here... do you mean `@total = @like.count - @dislike.count` perhaps instead? ie are you trying to store the total? if not - then I really don't understand because you can't assign a value to `@like + @dislike` - that won't work. Can you explain what you expect to happen on that line of code?

Comment: In the index action: `@rating = Rating.all` when you are getting out a set of things (as opposed to just one), you should really use a plural variable-name eg here you should use `@ratings` - it's Rails best practice and makes it easier in future to see that you have more than one.

Comment: `user_signed_in? == true ? (user_sign == true) : (user_sign = false)` when you have a boolean value (eg `user_signed_in?`) then you don't need to explicitly check if it's true... you can just do this instead: `user_signed_in? ? (user_sign == true) : (user_sign = false)`. If `user_sign` is also a boolean then you can simplify this to `user_signed_in? ? user_sign : !user_sign`

Comment: In your controller, you have methods called `like`/`dislike` - but you are somehow trying to pass it a variable called `liked`/`disliked` - does this mean that these methods are *not* controller actions (ie you are *NOT* trying to use a link to get to them)? Because you can't pass a variable like that to a controller-action... if they are not controller actions, then which action calls those methods? Likewise, you call a method called `can_rate?` from several other methods... but the method at the top of your controller is called `can_rate(user_sign)` - ie quite different... which is correct?

Comment: @TarynEast Hey Taryn I'm sorry it took me so long to reply. I scraped the idea and continued the development of my website. I forgot what i was trying to do. Sorry to waste your time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

took me only a day after fiddling around with various gems I used [acts_as_votable](https://github.com/ryanto/acts_as_votable) gem to accomplish this. I'm using solidus as an engine that's why it was so difficult to make one from scratch which I was originally trying to do

Ratings controller

```
Spree::Product.class_eval  do
 module Spree
  class RatingsController < Spree::StoreController
    def like
        @product = Product.find(strong_prod_params)
        if spree_current_user
          if spree_current_user.voted_for?(@product) == false
            @product.liked_by spree_current_user

            registered
          elsif spree_current_user.voted_up_on?(@product)
            @product.unliked_by spree_current_user

          elsif spree_current_user.voted_down_on?(@product)
            @product.undisliked_by spree_current_user
            @product.liked_by spree_current_user

            registered
          end
        else
          flash[:notice] = "You need to be signed in to use this feature!"
        end
        redirect_to :back
      end

      def dislike
        @product = Product.find(strong_prod_params)
        #if user is signed in
       if spree_current_user
        #self explanatory
          if spree_current_user.voted_for?(@product) == false
            @product.disliked_by spree_current_user

            registered
          elsif spree_current_user.voted_down_on?(@product)
            @product.undisliked_by spree_current_user

          elsif spree_current_user.voted_down_on?(@product)
            @product.unliked_by spree_current_user
            @product.disliked_by spree_current_user

            registered
          end
        else
          flash[:notice] = "You need to be signed in to use this feature!"
        end
        redirect_to :back
      end

      def registered
        if @product.vote_registered?

          flash[:notice] = "You have rated this!"
        else
          flash[:notice] = "Something went wrong!"
        end
      end
      private
      #just some cautionary strong parameters.
      def strong_prod_params
        params.require(:product).permit(:id)
      end

    end
  end
end
```

Handling the model and database are in the documentation. If it doesn't work then try replacing ***Product.find(strong_prod_params)*** to ***Product.find(params[:id])***
Here's how I call my like method in case you were wondering

```
<%= link_to 'like', {:action => 'like', :controller => '/spree/ratings', :id => @product.id}, method: :put %>
```

Here's my routes

```
Spree::Core::Engine.routes.prepend do
 put '/ratings' => 'ratings#like'
end
```